# Cardinality, which entity is the owner and how to add the proper notations

Tags: java, persistence

(Thank you for redirecting to appropiate topic if it exists, could not find myself)

Person A can own from 0 to N TVSeries.
Each TVSerie can have from 1 to N Episodes.

Could you please clarify how this is exactly coded in java (@XtoY notations) and who owns who in this particular scenario? (@mappedby = "...") etc.

For some reason I reason this backwards and I'd love a simple and clear example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Person` and `TVSeries` is a one to many relationship.

`TVSeries` and `Episodes` is a one to many relationship.

So in JPA(or Hibernate), you need to set up relationship just like that.

Study this example from mkyong:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

In his example, the one to many relationship is `Stock` and `StockDailyRecord`. So just change the object name to `Person`,`TVSeries`,`Episodes`, etc and following what he did, you will get it working pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you Jason! So far I understand how the cardinality works, I fail to translate that into code using the appropiate notations in the appropiate entities. Your example was helpful. What I am trying to do is define the relationship when declaring variables, not in functions.